# which way is better in java?

Tags: java, networking, sockets, rmi

I want write a **Special Messenger**(should be able to some transaction) with RMI(Remote Method Invocation) or Network(Socket) , It should be

1. Fast
2. Secure
3. Convenience(easy to use)
4. and of course beautiful :)

It's for a big LAN and it should be able to handle our transaction in Oracle DB !!!

which way is better in java? RMI or Network ???

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Could you clarify the question please. "Which is better in Java" doesn't quite tell me what you're looking for.

Comment: Please include specifics such as verifying that you are using Java on both ends and such.  Also since you mention 'it should be able to handle our transaction in Oracle DB' are your needing to use transaction control?

Comment: Thanks Dear SOA ; yes some transaction must be control with it;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMI Programming Services Reach out and touch someone. Object-oriented distributed computing is all about communication between objects that live in different virtual machines. Remote Method Invocation (RMI) makes sending a message to an object in Timbuktu as easy as invoking a method on a local object. RMI is 100% Pure Java TM. And best of all, it's built into the core Java libraries (version 1.1 and higher). This module introduces RMI and covers its strengths and weaknesses as a platform for distributed computing. Reference RMI Programming:
http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/rmi/index.jsp 
http://www.eve-it.com/solutions/rmi.html

Socket Programming:
 http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking whether RMI or low-level socket programming is better? I'd say unless you had a real good reason, use something more high-level for the networking. A drawback with RMI would be that it is tied to Java. If that is a problem, you can look at other, more cross-platform remoting protocols.

Either way, the networking issue seems to be completely unrelated to "handling transactions with an Oracle DB".

Comment: Thanks Dear  Thilo , Ok your mean is Networking is better for me no?

Comment: No. More higher-level frameworks (such as RMI) would be better.